# Shopware 6 sw-entity-single-select empty options

Tags: shopware

I am using the `<sw-entity-single-select` tag, but the items inside are empty. The amount of items are correct, and the console.log data on change also gives correct data. Maybe i'm missing an attribute or something?

This is the tag

```html
<sw-entity-single-select
    v-model="component.dimensionType"
    entity="dimension"
    :localMode="component.isNew()"
    label="Koppel dimensie aan component"
    @change="setDimension"
>
</sw-entity-single-select>
```

And this is the entity definition of dimension

```php
return new FieldCollection(
            [
                (new IdField('id', 'id'))->addFlags(new Required(), new PrimaryKey()),
                (new StringField('title', 'title'))->addFlags(new Required()),
                (new OneToManyAssociationField(
                    'components',
                    ComponentDefinition::class,
                    'dimension_type',
                    'id'))->addFlags(new RestrictDelete(), new ReverseInherited('dimensionType')
                ),
            ]
        );
```

And the relation the other way around in component

```php
new FkField('dimension_type', 'dimensionType', DimensionDefinition::class),
                new ManyToOneAssociationField(
                    'dimension',
                    'dimension_type',
                    DimensionDefinition::class
                ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you missed `labelProperty` attribute which specifies the text of each item.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a custom entity Vue doesn't know which property to take as a name.
Therefore you have to pass your custom name within the provided slot of the [sw-entity-single-select component](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/49850767dba0a0091eca90479a6a4bfd0f3147d9/src/Administration/Resources/app/administration/src/app/component/form/select/entity/sw-entity-single-select/sw-entity-single-select.html.twig#L70-L95).

An Example:

```
<sw-entity-single-select
    v-model="component.dimensionType"
    entity="dimension"
    :localMode="component.isNew()"
    label="Koppel dimensie aan component"
    @change="setDimension">

    <template #result-item="{ item, index }">
        <slot name="result-item" v-bind="{ item, index }">
            <li is="sw-select-result" v-bind="{ item, index }">
                {{ item.title }}
            </li>
        </slot>
    </template>
</sw-entity-single-select>
```

Comment: That has nothing really to do with Shopware itself - It's about Vue.
Within your `setDimension` method you can get the current selected value if you pass a param to your method - And based on this value you can do your thing.
Take a look at the Vue Docs for Event Handling https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html